# How to convert Html to Pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, dom, dompdf

I am having some issue in converting HTML Page Content to PDF Using Php.
Please see my code below..

```
<?php
    require_once("../dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php");
    require_once("../dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
    function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE){    
            $dompdf= new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    }


    $filename='file_name';
    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
    $html=file_get_contents('file_html.php');
    pdf_create($html, $filename, 'A4', 'portrait');

?>
```

The error message I get is:

> Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'DOMPDF_autoload' not found (function 'DOMPDF_autoload' not found or invalid function name)' in dom-pdf\dom-pdf1.php:3 Stack trace: #0 dom-pdf\dom-pdf1.php(3): spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload') #1 {main} thrown in dom-pdf\dom-pdf1.php on line 3

Please tell me how can i correct error showing here

```
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
```

Actually i am trying to generate and design pdf from this code so please help me to correct this.

Comment: Well, that function needs the name of an existing function as an argument. You code never declares such a function. Where should it come from? Where _is_ that function?

Comment: Which function should i declare spl_autoload_register or ?

Comment: That function is (obviously) not defined when you hand it over in that function call, yes. That is what the error message says, isn't it? I doubt you should _declare_ it, since... what would you implement in it? More likely that function is already declared somewhere in that library you want to use, but not included yet.

Comment: now i included library file require_once("../dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php"); But now showing error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'spl_autoload_register' (T_STRING)

Comment: Actually I doubt that when adding that line you get the error message you posted...

Comment: yaa correct so it's showing

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the README in git (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), depending on how you've installed the code, you either need to include the autoloader, or include vendor/autoload:

If you installed using composer:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you installed manually from the git repo:

```
// include autoloader
require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
```

Comment: I have included but now it's showing error                                                              Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'spl_autoload_register' (T_STRING)

Comment: Without seeing your full code I'm not really able to offer much more advise - I'd suggest reading through the DOMPDF documentation carefully, and using the autoloaders in the way it suggests - it's unlikely that the syntax error is being caused by DOMPDF itself, so it's probable that you've got unmatched quotes or something similar in your code, or you are using an incompatible version of PHP etc.

Comment: @arkascha - which file? https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/autoload.inc.php is the file that is being required - if the fie wasn't there, it wouldn't be a parse error you'd be getting...

Comment: It  may be it's outdated version let me check then i will update the whole code Thankyou so much for suggestion to both

Answer (score 0):

It Works Properly anybody can use it...

```
<?php
  require_once ("Dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");


  $pdf_content='
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">                           
  #pdf_header, #pdf_container{ border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px; }               
  #pdf_header{ margin:10px auto 0px; border-bottom:none; }              
  table{ width:580px; }
  #pdf_container{margin:0px auto; }
  .rpt_title{ background:#99CCFF; }                                                         
  </style>
 <body>
 <div id="pdf_header" >
 <div id="maindiv1" style="border:1px solid blue;width:500px;height:230px">            
    <div  style="border:0px solid red;width:100px;height:80px;float:left;">
     <img src="<img src="http://incroyablefuture.com/blog/img/small-icon.jpg"/>" />
    </div>
    <h1 style="color:blue;font-family:sans-     serif;float:left;width:390px;margin-top:10;text-align:center;border:0px solid red;">enterployee.com</h1>
   <div style="border:0px solid red;width:100%;height:120px;float:left;">
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;">
       Enterployee.com is a employee relationship management tool for enterprise. It’s a fully managed notification platform for employees.
       We have a vision to make organizations more professional and organized. After getting an enterployee account organizations can notify their employees easily and employees can connect with their company in better way.
       </p>

    </div>

    <div style="border:0px solid red;width:80px;height:30px;float:right;">
    </div>
</div> 
</div></body></html>'
;

$name = date("Ymd").rand().'.pdf';
$reportPDF=createPDF(12, $pdf_content, 'example', $name );
function createPDF($pdf_userid, $pdf_content, $pdf_For, $filename){
$path='pdf-lib/';    
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pdf_content);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($path.$filename, $output);
return $filename;       
}   
echo '<a href="pdf-lib/'.$name.'" > Download as PDF </a>';
  ?>
```

You can create pdf from a html format..